# Concatenate dynamic columns in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

Say I have the following table:

```
MemberName | ProjectCode | HoursWorked
John Smith | ABC, Inc.   |     5     
John Smith | Intel, Inc. |     3     
Mike Jones | Sesame St.  |     10
```

and this is the statement I used to get it:

```
SELECT MemberName, ProjectCode, SUM(HoursWorked)
FROM table
GROUP BY MemberName, ProjectCode
ORDER BY MemberName
```

How would I be able to yield the following results where there's an additional column added that has all Project Codes and Hours worked for the specific member concatenated into one column?

```
MemberName | HoursWorked | Details
John Smith |      8      | ABC, Inc.-5, Intel, Inc.-3
Mike Jones |      10     | Sesame St.-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FOR XML PATH to concatenate the multiple rows of data into a single row:

```
;with cte as
(
  select membername, hoursworked,
    projectcode +'-'+cast(hoursworked as varchar(10)) projectcode
  from yourtable
)
select c.membername,
  sum(c.hoursworked) hoursworked,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + projectcode
          FROM cte c2
          where c.membername = c2.membername
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS details
from cte c
group by c.membername;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1e35/1)